# main() always returns int?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should main() return in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-c)
>   [why do we give int main in c++ and not void main?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449851/why-do-we-give-int-main-in-c-and-not-void-main)

I've started learning C++ and the following question came up to my mind: **main()** always return int? Cannot I declare **void main()** instead of **int main()**?

Thanks you!

Comment: The main function *in the global namespace* must return an `int`, as per the Standard.

Comment: This link is worth reading: http://users.aber.ac.uk/auj/voidmain.cgi

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `main()` must return `int`. The return value is passed back to the operating system, to indicate whether the program ran successfully: zero means success.

However, you can leave the `return` statement out of `main` (and only `main`) if you like; in that case, it will return zero.

Answer (score 1):

It has to return an integer value. The returned value tells the computer what, if any, error codes there were. Returning 0 will tell it that there were no errors in the program.