# My code doesn't returns an output. It returns only exit code

Tags: c

I wanted to reverse half of the arrays inputs with the other half.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    void main() {
       double size = 5;
       int array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
       int half_size = ceil(size / 2);
       for(int i = 0; i < half_size; i++){
           int a;
           int rev = size - (i + 1);
           array[i] = a;
           array[i] = array[rev];
           array[rev] =  a;`enter code here`
           }
       printf("%d", array[5]);
       }
```

Comment: `array[5]` is out of bounds. Also I would suggest to think about a way to avoid floating point numbers here.

Comment: You can't print a whole array like that: you must print each element in a loop.

Comment: If you want to do exact arithmetic, use int.  Double is for inexact arithmetic over a greater range than an int can hold.

Comment: What is the purpose of the line `array[i] = a;`, followed immediately by another (different) assignment to array[i]?

Comment: `void main()` is wrong. [What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/204476/995714), [main() always returns int?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12570837/995714). And the output isn't returned, it's printed out

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Eugene Sh.'s and @FredK's suggestions. The line `array[5]` in the line `printf("%d", array[5]);` is out of bound since `array` only have indexes from 0 to 4. Since I assume you want to print out the last element in the array, you should change it to `printf("%d", array[4]);`. Another thing is that your assignment expression `array[i] = a;` is wrong. I assume the expression is part of the swapping process from element in index `i` with element in index `rev`. If that was the case then you should change it to `a = array[i];` instead. I update you code according to my suggestion and it outputs the correct result. I added the for loop to verify that the `array` values are reversed for testing purpose. You can delete it after you're done testing.

```
#include <math.h>
int main() {
    double size = 5;
    int array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int half_size = ceil(size / 2);
    for(int i = 0; i < half_size; i++){
        int a;
        int rev = size - (i + 1);
        a = array[i];
        array[i] = array[rev];
        array[rev] =  a;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("%d", array[4]);
}
```