# Compiler seems to reject class identifier initialization before member

Tags: c++, compilation, mingw

Please understand that I have a strong fever while writing this, and, in addition, it is years ago since I have used C++ - or classes for that matter.

My problem consists in the g++ compiler rejecting my calling of the class identifier (+ the member specifier), and the actual member of that class.

Here is what I mean:

```
class window{
public:
int borderX, borderY, menu_item;
};
```

If I choose to call one of these members (boderX, borderY, menu_item), like so:

```
window.borderX = [some value here];
```

I get an error in return:

> error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token

When I look at cplusplus' website, this code is NOT grammatically incorrect. Yet, it refuses to compile?

Here is an example from cplusplus' website:

```
class CRectangle {
    int width, height;
  public:
    void set_values (int, int);
    int area (void) {return (width * height);}
};
CRectangle rect;
  rect.set_values (3,4);
```

This code does NOT compile either!

It returns this error:

> error: 'rect' does not name a type

I don't understand why it returns these errors. Window IS used as an identifier - or a type thereof. And secondly, it won't EVEN compile the code from the very website itself which TEACHES the use of C++.

I am waiting to be corrected on these matters.
Also, for the record, I am using MingW. Both Code::Blocks and Netbeans yield the same results (yes I KNOW they're IDEs, and not compilers.)

Comment: Your `window` example needs an object. The second needs a main function ([see reproduced compiler error](http://liveworkspace.org/code/147aeaa560062ccb4985245ab9549d9d)).

Comment: The first with `window` doesn't work because you're accessing non-static data members on a type – you need an _object_ first. The second with `CRectangle` doesn't work because you haven't defined `CRectangle::set_values`.

Comment: @ildjarn, True, though that's a linker error. Better finding it now than after it compiles and just gives a new error, though.

Comment: Actually he has an object :) Its window, he needs an instance of the object.

Comment: @JonathanCruz, That's a class. An instance of a class is an object.

Comment: @Chris hm yea actually you're right :)

Comment: The problem you're having with the example is that you need to put it inside a function (the last line for sure, but you can put the whole thing into a function if you want).  The last line is a statement, and you can't put statements at namespace scope.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I hope you feel better soon. Part of the reason that you have received two answers that don't satisfy you is that your question is incomplete. Please post a complete minimal program that demonstrates your problem. See http://SSCCE.ORG for more information.

Comment: A question before I get coding: do I need to close this page since my issue has been resolved--can I do that?

Chris, I was in fact experiencing odd linker issues (which I don't think relates to my clumsiness) in Code::Blocks, hence switching to Netbeans. Of course, I realize that switching IDE should not resolve such issues - though it seems to have done so.

I have actually defined the set_values function, Ildjarn, but it's done in a header - hence your lack of awareness.
Once again, thanks everyone for the kind help.

Comment: @user1707244 If an answer resolves your problem, upvote and click the checkmark next to it to mark it as "accepted". That "closes" your question.

Answer (score 4):

'window' defines the class, but you need to make an instance of that class in order to use it's non-static members and methods.

You can either create an instance on the stack,

```
window w;
w.borderX = [some value here];
```

Or create one on the heap,

```
window *w = new window();
w->borderX = [some value here];
```

Comment: But creating one on the heap creates all kinds of *new* (haha) problems if you don't use something with RAII.

Comment: Having to edit again. Don't want to impose an impolite position.
But please read properly, the original post, before posting. I already declared how it does not work properly.
Again, don't take it ill.

Comment: (Adding a comment since I think this is a good place to start.) @user1707244 Do you have the `window` class defined in a separate file from your `main` function? If so, what do you have for `#include` statements? Also, how are you calling your compiler?

Comment: Good question. Yes, I do have it in a header, but it's not a problem.

I knew that this might have been the problem, so I thought ahead and added my class declaration in my main.cpp.

So, to answer your question, yes, I have.

Comment: @user1707244 Ok, then. My suspicion, there, is alleviated.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

First you declare the class. In window.h

```
#include <iostream> // for cout and endl

class Window{
public:
    int borderX, borderY, menu_item;
};
```

In your main file where you start the program:

```
#include <window.h>
int main() {
    // 1. make an instance of Window
    Window w;         

    // 2. set some values
    w.borderX = 12;   
    w.borderY = 8;
    w.menu_item = 7;

    // 3. print the values
    std::cout << "X: "  << w.borderX 
              << " Y: " << w.borderY 
              << " menu item: " << w.menu_item << std::endl;

    //OR with a pointer
    // 1. create a new pointer that points to 
    //    an instance of Window (which is also create in the process)
    Window pw = new Window(); 

    // 3. set some values
    pw->borderX = 9;           
    pw->borderY = 12;
    pw->menu_item = 18;

    // 3. print the values
    std::cout << "X: "<< pw->borderX << " Y: " << pw->borderY 
              << " menu item: " << pw->menu_item << std::endl;

    // 4. Rule: for every *new* (new Window()) there is 1 delete
    //    So every pointer should be deleted somewhere 1 time to avoid memory leaks
    delete pw; 

    return 0;
}
```

And i hope you get better soon. Having fever is not funny.

Comment: Does NOT work!!! I already showed how it didn't work in my original post!
Sorry for being impolite...
Returns: main.cpp:8:1: error: 'window' does not name a type
And: main.cpp:9:1: error: 'w' does not name a type

Comment: FYI: Your `main` has the wrong signature. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449851/why-do-we-need-to-use-int-main-and-not-void-main-in-c

Comment: Note that C++ is case sensitive. He's using upper case Window in his example and your error has lowercase "window", so you either typed the error wrong or didn't copy/paste his code exactly.

Comment: You also need "std::endl" instead of endl;

Comment: Right, i use uppercase for window because its a convention. Names representing types must be in mixed case starting with upper case. @Robᵩ thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: You're also using w-> instead of pw-> for the pointer to a window references. Compiles after that fix.

Comment: @user1707244 i assumed you would put it all in 1 file to test it out. I will add a header file in the example.

Comment: I am aware of the std namespace, and am also aware of case sensitivity.
These two factors do not play a role, as I have already thought ahead of them.

Comment: http://ideone.com/57UEw Compiles fine here, so maybe you're not including the correct files in your ide/build tools?

Comment: @user1707244 then why dont you use it accordingly? Sorry just trying to help here. This code works.

Comment: Yes, Jonathan, it does work. This is a case of having very little sleep plus being sick (lightheaded), and also having forgot the basics of class declaration. It does work now. Thanks everyone for sticking through my clumsiness.

Comment: :) no worries. Glad i(we) could help.