# printing the value at the pointer returned by a function

Tags: c, static

I am trying to access a static variable from other file the following way.
Can you please help in printing the value of variable 'c' in file1.c.

Find the code below

File1.c

```
void main(void)
{
    int m;
    m=func_ret();
    printf("\n m = %d\n",m);
}
```

File2.c

```
static int c =5;
int *func_ret(void)
{
    printf("\n c = [%d]\n",c);
    return &c;
}
```

Comment: `int m,`---> `int m;`

Comment: You simply can't, remove static from `c`'s definition and it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `file1.c` to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int *func_ret(void);

int main(void)
{
    int *m = 0;
    m=func_ret();
    printf("\n m = %d\n",*m);
    //some code
    return 0;
}
```

And `file2.c` to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int c = 5;
int *func_ret(void)
{
    printf("\n c = [%d]\n",c);
    return &c;
}
```

Additionally, you should make a habit of using `int main(void)` instead of `void main()`.
Since that part in not really in scope of this question, instead of writing about it at length, I'll share the link to the related question:
[int main(void) vs void main()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9356510/4228131) and,
[Why do we need to use `int main` and not `void main` in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/449851/4228131)

Comment: Thanks WedaPashi, 
ur code changes worked,
i just had assign the return value to a integer pointer variable in place of integer variable.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here, you're returning a pointer from `func_ret()` and then, trying to capture the return value in an `int` variable, then trying to print the value using `%d`. It mostly invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

For reference, `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.3

> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type, the behaviour is undefined. The result need not be in the range of values of any integer type.

Solution: You need to change the type of `m` from an `int` to `int *`. You have to use appropriate format specifiers also.

Also note, the recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.

Comment: Even I am trying to figure out why would someone downvote this answer.

Comment: I didn't down vote, but in most cases conversions from pointer to int are harmless. Worst case scenario is that you will print some garbage value.

Comment: @Lundin sir, I agree with you but at some cases, it can cause problems, right? so, better to use the recommended and defined way, Moreover, I think, in OP's case, it's a matter of oversight. The conversion is not intentional. :-)

Comment: the capturing of the return value doesnt invoke the undefined behaviour since address is stored in the integer variable.
the code snippet in the question works where m prints the address of the variable C, but i wanted the value at C.
thanks for the explanation