# Default Return Type of main() in c/C++

Tags: c++, c, types

Why not char/float/double (other primitive data types) be return type of main()?

Comment: This may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449851/why-do-we-need-to-use-int-main-and-not-void-main-in-c

Comment: The canonical duplicate for these questions is [What should `main()` return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)

Answer (score 1):

Because that's how the language was designed, mostly.

Historically (i.e. before ISO/IEC 9899 was made), there was no `void`. Functions with a return value you didn't care about were declared without a return type, making the return type implicitly `int`. Back then, it didn't actually matter what `main()` returned, the code that called `main()` looked like this:

```
setup_stuff();
main(argc, argv);
exit(0);
```

When `main()` returned, the program was ended with an exit status of 0. Programs that wanted to return a nonzero exit status had to explicitly call `exit()`. Plan 9 retains this model. Some people thought this was too restrictive and changed this code to return the return value of `main()` instead:

```
setup_stuff();
exit(main(argc, argv));
```

And that's how we ended up with `main()` returning an `int`. C++ just copied this design aspect from C as far as I know.

Comment: Int is the default return type of main()