# Purpose of int with respect to main code in C++

Tags: c++, int, program-entry-point

I am just starting out in C++ and we are learning about typical statements in code.  One that we typically use is `int main()` at the start of the actual program portion.  I understand we can also use `void main()`.
My question is, why do we use `int`? I thought this was for defining variable types.  Are we actually declaring that the whole code is a variable?

Comment: You cannot actually use `void main()`. It's not allowed by the language. Your compiler may allow it, but it isn't portable.

Comment: `int main()` defines a function, not a variable. The leading type is the type of value the function returns.

Comment: In a way, yes, the whole program is a variable, an `int` which the program returns on exit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449851/why-do-we-need-to-use-int-main-and-not-void-main-in-c

More info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c

Comment: If it is defined `int` then it expects to return a value. This is the "result". If it is `void` it does not expect to return a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `main` function (which is your entry point to the program) is defined by the C++ standard to *always* return `int`. `void main` is *not* valid according to the standard (even if your compiler accepts it).

The purpose of the `int` return value is to return a value to the operating system, telling it whether your program completed successfully or not. There are two well-defined macros available for returning such a value that you can depend on having a sane meaning - they are `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`. You *can* return other values than those, but *only* those are guaranteed to have a sane semantic meaning - any other value is going to be platform/OS dependent (and while `EXIT_SUCCESS` is *usually* zero, you can't depend on that - on VMS (for example) that is not true, so you really should use the macros in portable code - and regardless, `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` communicates meaning much clearer than `return 0;`).

`main` is special compared to *all* other functions though, in that if no value is explicitly returned it implicitly returns `EXIT_SUCCESS` - *I* personally don't like relying on that though; I prefer explicitly returning what I intend to return.

Comment: Worth adding: the `return` statement can be completely omitted from the `main` function and if that function completes, `EXIT_SUCCESS` is implied.

Comment: @erip good point. Added a bit about that.